# ZeroBrane Studio: top bar is unreachable. Window can't be moved

Tags: macos, zerobrane

ZeroBrane Studio 1.90 on MacOS 10.15.7

The minimize, maximize buttons of the finder handle bar are not reachable
since they are at a negative y position (outside the desktop screen)

Fullscreen can be called via menu entry, but this is no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the IDE and open its configuration file (`$HOME/Library/Preferences/ZeroBraneStudio Preferences`, as described in the [session configuration section](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-general-preferences#session-configuration)) with your favorite editor. Find `x` and `y` values under the `[MainFrame]` section. If they are negative, change them to some positive value and save the file. Restart the IDE.

Comment: Thank you Paul, this worked. The value was y = -46. I updated from the earlier version which was certainly not outside of the desktop. So I think this should go into a bug report and be investigated further.